# Is there a localizable way to format numbers with HTML?

Tags: html, localization, language-translation

Different countries have different [decimal separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) and thousand separators:

- English: Decimal (`.`), Thousand (`,`)
- German: Decimal (`,`), Thousand (`.`)

When writing text, is there a way to annotate numbers so that translation engines have an easier time?

Something like

```
(1) Germany has a population of <number>83000000</number>.
(2) <number>57.3</number>% of them are Christian.
(3) Both are in <number>12345678.9</number>.
```

where the numbers should get rendered as the following for English users:

```
(1) Germany has a population of 83,000,000.
(2) 57.3% of them are Christian.
(3) Both are in 12,345,678.9
```

And translation engines could easily convert the numbers to:

```
(1) Germany has a population of 83.000.000.
(2) 57,3% of them are Christian.
(3) Both are in 12.345.678,9
```

Google Translate gets (1) and (2) right without annotation, but not (3).

(Note: This is a more basic variant of my question [Does a standardized way to annotate quantities to allow automatic localization exist in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53097575/562769))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```js
// For English Users
$(function(){
 $("#ban").text((1234567.89).toLocaleString('en'))
})

/*
// For German Users
$(function(){
 $("#ban").text((1234567.89).toLocaleString('de'))
})
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ban">
  
</div>
```